# problem in show view when delete foreign key?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a student table and an education table, with the PK of the education table as a foreign key of the student table. However, when the education is deleted, the student no longer appears in the view. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: @user818566, it is not very clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to prevent user from deleting or prevent user from viewing deleted "education"?

Comment: So... when an education record is deleted, the student record that had a foreign(?) key to the deleted record doesn't show up anymore?

Comment: Can you **show us** the table structures, the view definition and some sample data?? As is, we can **guess at best** ....

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you are asking I think you should first rethink your database structure.

Answer the following questions:

1. Does it make sense to have a `student` with a non existant `education`?

   This would be the case if you deleted an `education` in your `Educations` table but students with a FK to that `education` row lived on in your database. This seems to be what you are asking for but it doesn't make much sense as it doesn't mantain data integrity.
2. Should you be allowed to delete an `education` if students are enlisted in said `education`?

   If it shouldn`t be allowed then you would only need to disable cascade deleting in your 1 to many relationship and your problem would be solved.
3. If an `eduction` is deleted, should all students assigned to said education remain in the data base?

   This is what you want but with the structure of your database it is not straightforward to achieve.

Easier solution?

One would be to create 3 tables instead of 2:

1. Educations
2. Students
3. StudentsEducationAssignments

In 1 you store eveything that has to do ONLY with your `education` entities. In 2 only what has to do with your `student` entities (note that what type of `education` they choose is not something that ONLY describes the `student`). In 3 you store what students are assigned to what educations.

This way, if you delete an `education`, the students assigned to it will not be deleted, only the information that ties students to that specific `education`. You keep database integrity easier this way.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

From the information you have given, my guess is that you have enforced referencial integrity on your database. This means that when you deleted a row in education, the students that were linked with it were also deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I find that it is good practice to never delete data from tables due to other fields being dependent on them. Instead, you should have a boolean value in the table that is called 'IsDeleted' and just change that to True when you want to 'Delete' it, and when you pull data make sure you filter out anything that has the 'IsDeleted' set to 'True'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an OUTER JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN in your view?

If you show us the view definition we might be able to help more, without it we're just guessing.